# Is my website compatible with a specific browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

What's the best way of checking the compatibility of a website with a specific version of a browser.
For instance, I know how my website will be rendered on the latest version of FireFox which I've installed it before, but I don't know how it'd be shown on previous versions.

IE has an option to render a page like previous version but firstly I've heard that it's not as the same as the original version and secondly it's just IE and what about others?

Answer (score 2):

> What's the best way of checking the compatibility of a website with a specific version of a browser.

Check it in that browser.  Only you know what "compatible" means, and what sort of compatibility you're willing to accept for your site.

There are some tools that can make it easier.  For example, [CrossBrowserTesting.com](http://crossbrowsertesting.com/) can render your page in various browsers for easy inspection.  They also allow for running Selenium tests, and a VNC session for manually testing your pages.  There are many alternatives to CrossBrowserTesting.com as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can make multiple versions of Firefox and Seamonkey co-exist with each other. Install them into separate directories and create a different profile for each browser you instal.

for chrome, the vast majority of people who uses the Chrome browser will be using the latest version, since that browser automatically updates itself whether you want it or not.

check out this website for more info about other browsers:
http://www.thesitewizard.com/webdesign/multiplebrowsers.shtml

hope this helps